# How to troubleshoot a possible HDCP issue without a PC

Tags: display, hdmi, xbox360, hdcp

Any ways I can test HDCP related problems with just an xbox 360 and a new [LG TV/Monitor](http://www.lg.com/uk/monitors/lg-M2762DP-tv-monitor) connected over HDMI?

The monitor reports 'no signal' when the xbox is connected, yet other devices work (tested with my blu ray player).

The xbox works when connected to an older Monitor via HDMI (which may not be HDCP compliant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was asked to troubleshoot why this new monitor would not work with the xbox360.

I tested the xbox360 with the original cable on a non-HDCP compliant monitor with the original HDMI cable (a cheap one) and it worked.

I tested my blu ray player on the TV with the original HDMI cable, it would not work (displayed 'No Signal).

I tested my blu ray player on the TV with my gold plated (expensive) HDMI HDCP compliant cable and it worked.

I tested the xbox360 with my expensive HDCP compliant HDMI cable, it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Check your HDMI cable. Sometimes certain cables will not have all possible wires connected. Therefore a very easy fix may be to just connect a different HDMI cable.

Then again, have you updated your TV's firmware lately? More likely, that's the problem. You may simply be due for a firmware update that will correct/improve/fix your TV's content protection locking routines (and possibly stop mistaking certain content as being "protected").

Or it may be that you're trying to play protected content and everything is working! Therefore, you might try decreasing the resolution and play it in standard definition (SD) since a lot of times the content locking won't care. Content protection locks usually only care if you're playing protected content in high definition - aka HDCP.

Comment: I've solved the problem with a different (more expensive) HDMI cable. Still looking for an easier way to test for HDCP compliancy, but thanks for your answer!